# razor foreach in model can not be used

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-2

Good day,

I have this viewmodel

```
public class ProjectTypeViewModel
{      
    public string CategoryName{ get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProjectType> Tipo { get; set; }
}
public class ProjectType
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(512)]
    [Required]
    public string Type{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string AddedBy { get; set; }
    public Category Category{ get; set; }
    public Guid? CategoryId{ get; set; }

}
```

I want to return thae ProjectTypeViewModel into my view

```
@model  List<MyProject.ViewModels.ProjectTypeViewModel>
@foreach(var tipo in Model )
{

}
```

I have a problem here, my model displays the following error:

> foreach statement can not operate in variables of type
>   ProjectTypeViewModel because does not contain a definition for 
>   GetEnumerator.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share to controller code which creates model and passes to the view? Are you getting this error at runtime or compile time ?

Comment: thank you very much por taking your time. I already solved it, I was getting the error while writing my view. I just had to use IEnumerable<model>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to access list in model like below

```
@model  MyProject.ViewModels.ProjectTypeViewModel
@foreach(var tipo in Model.Tipo)
{

}
```